# How to map these 2 classes using Automapper

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2, automapper

I have these 2 classes, I am trying to map DropOffLocationRequest to Package class, but it is failing to map DropOffGeoLocation, i have used the ResolveCore as well but giving me error

> **Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping**

If i ask automapper to ignore the DropOffGeoLocation of Package class while mapping then there is no error and works fine.

> **Mapping code**

```
public void Configure()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<DropOffLocationRequest, Package>()
                .ForMember(des => des.DropOffGeoLocation., opt => opt.ResolveUsing<DropOffGeoLocationResolver>())
                .ForMember(des => des.Name, src => src.Ignore())
                .ForMember(des => des.IdNo, src => src.Ignore())
                .ForMember(des => des.IsEnabled, src => src.Ignore())
                .ForMember(des => des.Comments, src => src.Ignore())
                .ForMember(des => des.RowCreateDate, src => src.Ignore())
                .ForMember(des => des.RowUpdateDate, src => src.Ignore()));
        }
public class DropOffLocationRequest
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
        public ActionType ActedBy { get; set; }
        public DevicePlatform Device { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset DeviceDateTimeOffSet { get; set; }
    }
public partial class Package
    {       

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string IdNo { get; set; }
        public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
        public System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography DropOffGeoLocation { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset> RowCreateDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset> RowUpdateDate { get; set; }
    }
```

> **ResolveCore class**

```
public class DropOffGeoLocationResolver : ValueResolver<DropOffLocationRequest, Package>
    {
        protected override Package ResolveCore(DropOffLocationRequest source)
        {
            var point = string.Format("POINT({1} {0})", source.Latitude, source.Longitude);
            return new Package { DropOffGeoLocation = DbGeography.FromText(point) };
        }

    }
```

Don't know what i am messing up.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your value resolver is creating an entire `Package`, but it should just be creating a `DbGeography` (since you are using the value resolver to map just the `DropOffLocation` property).

Try this instead:

```
public class DropOffGeoLocationResolver :
    ValueResolver<DropOffLocationRequest, DbGeography>
{
    protected override DbGeography ResolveCore(DropOffLocationRequest source)
    {
        var point = string.Format("POINT({1} {0})", source.Latitude, source.Longitude);
        return DbGeography.FromText(point);
    }
}
```